# flextable rownames formatting

Tags: r, dataframe, flextable

`padding()` can be used to add indents to column values. Is there a way to do this with row names?

I guess I could add another column and then just modify their position but I wonder if there is a better way.

An example would be in the picture below, where the levels of Tumor grade are slightly indented compared to to the factor name.

I'd also like to use `italics()` on the row names, as can be done with the headers via `italics(x, part = header)` .

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dummy demo about how to add tabs to some rows in some columns and how to format the values.

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>% 
  slice(1:6) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "carname") %>% 
  flextable(col_keys = c("carname", "mpg")) %>% 
  autofit() %>% 
  italic(j = "carname", italic = TRUE) %>% 
  compose(
    i = ~ vs == 1,
          j = "carname",
          value = as_paragraph("\t", as_b(carname)))
```

[image]